# jQuery: Why does this not work?

Tags: jquery

OK, so I have this code, And It does not work, in fact, it seems to stop my whole script from working.

```
<p id="mbt>Text<p>  <-- This is in the .html file, The rest is in the .js file
    if ($(window).width()=<1000) {
        $('#mbt').css('color', '#fff');
    } else{
        $('#mbt').css('color', '#000');
    };
});
```

I am trying to make some text change color depending on screen size (because of background colors and visibility). I think it is the `if` that makes things not work.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Have you thought of responsive CSS/media queries rather than javascript?

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors?

Comment: =< should be <=

Comment: Where are your script tags?

Comment: Your browser has a huge range of tools available to help you. Open its "developer tools". One of those is a "console" which shows you errors, like the error on the `=<` above telling you it's an invalid expression.

Comment: i think there is method declaration problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
<p id="mbt">Text<p>
<script>
$(window).resize(function() {

    if ($(window).width() <= 1000) {
        $('#mbt').css('color', 'red');
    } else{
        $('#mbt').css('color', 'blue');
    };
});
</script>
```